# Ingress and nginx configuration issue

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a containerised application & I am trying to pass the header `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` from my nginx to my rails application.

but when i use this header, the readiness and liveliness probes start failing with status `502 and awaiting headers` and my deployment does not successfully complete.

Here is the outoput of `kubectl describe pod` where we see `502`

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  11m                   kubelet, gke-cluster-1-upgraded-pool--v82p  Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.16.0.1:3000/users/sign_in: dial tcp 10.16.0.221:3000: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  11m                   kubelet, gke-cluster-1-upgraded-pool--v82p  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 502
  Warning  Unhealthy  11m                   kubelet, gke-cluster-1-upgraded-pool--v82p  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 502
  Warning  Unhealthy  11m                   kubelet, gke-cluster-1-upgraded-pool--v82p  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.16.0.1:3000/users/sign_in: dial tcp 10.16.0.221:3000: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  11m                   kubelet, gke-cluster-1-upgraded-pool--v82p  Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.16.0.1:3000/users/sign_in: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  BackOff    84s (x33 over 8m56s)  kubelet, gke-cluster-1-upgraded-pool--v82p  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Previously the header value was `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;`

below is the relevant part of my `nginx.conf`

```
http {
  set_real_ip_from 1.2.3.4; -- example ip
  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
  real_ip_recursive on;

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    client_max_body_size 16m;
    location @app {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    }
  }
}
```

below is my deployment file, i have tried to keep only the relevant parts and removed volumne mounts and db connection settings

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend

spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: nginx-config
          image: my_nginx
          command: ['/bin/sh', '-c']
          args: ["sed -i -e 's/gzip_types/gzip_types application\\/json/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && mv /etc/nginx/* /etc/nginx-new/"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nginx-config
              mountPath: /etc/nginx-new
        - name: copy-assets
          image: unicorn_image
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp -a /app/public/* /mnt/']
          volumeMounts:
            - name: assets
              mountPath: /mnt
      containers:
        - name: unicorn
          image: unicorn_image
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /users/sign_in
              port: 3000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10  
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /users/sign_in
              port: 3000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10  
        - name: nginx
          image: my_nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /users/sign_in
              port: 80
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10  
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /users/sign_in
              port: 80
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10  
          volumeMounts:
            - name: assets
              mountPath: /var/www
              readOnly: true
            - name: nginx-config
              mountPath: /etc/nginx
```

**Update**: i see that the nginx container is not getting created. Please see below

`kubectl exec -it backend-6f4974cfd6-jtnqk  -c nginx -- /bin/bash
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("nginx")`

Not sure as to how updating a header is causing an issue.

can anyone please point me in the right direction as to how i can fix it, Thanks.

Comment: can you please share the .yml configuration of k8s

Comment: hi @error404, i have updated the question with the deployment configuration file

Comment: @error404, i posted another update to the question

Answer (score 0):

**1.** According to the second question please add `volumes` an [emptyDir or hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes) into your `deployment.spec.template.spec section`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: ubuntu
        image: ubuntu
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", " echo test > /test1/index.html "]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-index
          mountPath: /test1
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-index
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-index
        emptyDir: {}
```

**2.** If you are using standard nginx image, please keep in mind that providing `args and commands` it will change f..e entrypoint [defined in Dockerimage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes)

**3.** In my opinion it will be better to use configMap in order to provide specific configuration into [nginx](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap)

Hope this help

Comment: hi @Hanx, i already have a emprtyDir volume, but i had not pasted that in the question as i thought that might not be relevant. I am however really stuck and not able to understand how adding a header can break a deployment.

Comment: please take a look at this [example](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/mergeable-ingress-types)